# Unable to insert returned API request into database - php

Tags: php, mysql, xml, multidimensional-array, foreach

**The error  Im currently getting :**

> Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]:
>   Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   'ac993f75-035b-433c-82e0-7b7a2d40802c' for key 'account_id''

The xml array Im trying to insert into my table is the following,

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [PaymentID] => ddbbf5df-16d7-4f07-be3b-50102d015473
    [Date] => 2016-11-30T00:00:00
    [BankAmount] => 14.38
    [Amount] => 14.38
    [Reference] => manual
    [CurrencyRate] => 1.000000
    [PaymentType] => ACCRECPAYMENT
    [Status] => AUTHORISED
    [UpdatedDateUTC] => 2016-11-30T20:50:25.73
    [Account] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [AccountID] => ac993f75-035b-433c-82e0-7b7a2d40802c
            [Code] => 090
        )

    [Invoice] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [Contact] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [ContactID] => 077866c9-462a-4713-9cc1-e75e3b4e29df
                    [ContactNumber] => SH-Customer-4236919494
                    [Name] => Joe Bloggs - 1
                )

            [CurrencyCode] => NZD
            [Type] => ACCREC
            [InvoiceID] => 2d06200d-69e7-488d-babb-db2664c09225
            [InvoiceNumber] => INV Order #1010
        )

)
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [PaymentID] => 1ea3b3ec-65a9-4fb8-8646-5376a6d2a6a3
    [Date] => 2016-11-30T00:00:00
    [BankAmount] => 14.38
    [Amount] => 14.38
    [Reference] => manual
    [CurrencyRate] => 1.000000
    [PaymentType] => ACCRECPAYMENT
    [Status] => AUTHORISED
    [UpdatedDateUTC] => 2016-11-30T20:50:28.007
    [Account] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [AccountID] => ac993f75-035b-433c-82e0-7b7a2d40802c
            [Code] => 090
        )

    [Invoice] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [Contact] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [ContactID] => e00f1e33-84b8-4c52-9428-f4c606069740
                    [Name] => Shopify Customer - UnleashedCET
                )

            [CurrencyCode] => NZD
            [Type] => ACCREC
            [InvoiceID] => cf5c20f1-cf82-4c74-9cce-7df0b7689ed4
            [InvoiceNumber] => INV Order #1011
        )

)
```

The function I am using for this is as follows :

```
function dataPayments ($array)
{
    $PDO = new PDO_connection();
    $pdo = $PDO->db_connection('test_db');
    $sql = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO db_xero_data_payments (
                      integration_id,
                      payment_id,
                      date,
                      bank_amount,
                      reference,
                      curreny_rate,
                      payment_type,
                      status,
                      updated_date,
                      account_id,
                      account_code,
                      contact_id,
                      contact_name,
                      currency_code,
                      type,
                      invoice_id,
                      invoice_number
                      )
                      VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)');

    foreach($array->Payments->Payment as $data)
    {
            $integration_id = "guid";
            $payment_id = $data->PaymentID;
            $date = $data->Date;
            $bank_amount = $data->BankAmount;
            $reference = $data->Reference;
            $curreny_rate = $data->CurrencyRate;
            $payment_type = $data->PaymentType;
            $status = $data->Status;
            $updated_date = $data->UpdatedDateUTC;
            $account_id = $data->Account->AccountID;
            $account_code = $data->Account->Code;
            $contact_id = $data->Invoice->Contact->ContactID;
            $contact_name = $data->Invoice->Contact->Name;
            $currency_code = $data->Invoice->CurrencyCode;
            $type = $data->Invoice->Type;
            $invoice_id = $data->Invoice->InvoiceID;
            $invoice_number = $data->Invoice->InvoiceNumber;

            $sql->execute([
                $integration_id,
                $payment_id,
                $date,
                $bank_amount,
                $reference,
                $curreny_rate,
                $payment_type,
                $status,
                $updated_date,
                $account_id,
                $account_code,
                $contact_id,
                $contact_name,
                $currency_code,
                $type,
                $invoice_id,
                $invoice_number
            ]);
    }
```

I am not sure of the correct loop structure in order to cycle through the data fields and move from one array to the next, can someone please help me ?

Comment: error message seems clear

Comment: you could add `on duplicate key update ...`?

Comment: @rtfm A++ combination of username and comment.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your table structure .

for key 'account_id''. May be it is  set as primary key or unique key. So it is violation of constraints.  We your trying to load a record with same account_id.

Comment: Thank you buddy, I completely over looked the table structure. You were correct, "account_id" was set as UNIQUE and I hadn't realised that the data was not unique. Thank you again :)